# Returning the argument from a list comprehension that's result satisfies <something>

Tags: functional-programming, python

It's a horrible title, I know; the basic explanation of what I mean is:

```
y=min([func(x) for x in range(z)])
```

As is, `y` contains the value of the output of `func(x_min)`. (`x_min` might not actually be the smaller value in the range).

Basically, I'm looking for a way to get `x_min` in this generic case in a more pythonic way. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
From SilentGhosts answer, (RTFM...), the equivalent of the above would be;

```
x_min=min(range(z),key=func)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `key` argument:

```
min(iterable, key=func)
```